# Complex numbers - minimum value proof

Tags: complex-numbers

**Question:**

> For:$$|z - z_1|^2+|z - z_2|^2+|z - z_3|^2+\cdots+|z - z_n|^2 = S$$
>   Prove that the minimum value of $S$ is when:$$z = \frac{z_1+z_2+z_3+\cdots+z_n}{n}$$

I have no idea how to even start this question. I tried to do it graphically but that didn't get me anywhere. However, I feel that the easiest proof for this would be graphically.

Comment: Hint: triangle inequality.

Comment: @AlexSilva Umm.... a wikipedia link or something? No idea what it is...

Comment: $|a_1+ \cdots +a_n| \leq |a_1| +\cdots + |a_n|.$

Comment: Fixed a mistake in the question. @AlexSilva

Answer (score 1):

In fact we have following identity,For any complex numbers $z_{1},z_{2},\cdots,z_{n}$,we have 
$$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|z-z_{j}|^2=n\left|z-\dfrac{z_{1}+z_{2}+\cdots+z_{n}}{n}\right|^2+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|z_{j}-\dfrac{z_{1}+z_{2}+\cdots+z_{n}}{n}\right|^2$$
so when
$$z=\dfrac{z_{1}+z_{2}+\cdots+z_{n}}{n}$$ then
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}|z-z_{j}|^2$$ is minimum.and the value is
$$n\cdot\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|z_{j}-\dfrac{z_{1}+z_{2}+\cdots+z_{n}}{n}\right|^2$$

Comment: Any proof or reference link with the proof? Thanks.

Comment: Something is wrong with the identity. The coefficient at $z^2$ on the left is 1 and on the right it is $n$.